# Send Email from Gmail with GAE Java using Socket

Tags: java, sockets, google-app-engine, smtp, gmail

I have a java google app engine (gae) app. My Recipients Emailed quota is 100. Billing is on and I  submit a request for an increase for 3 times but no luck. It is still 100. I do not want millions. 1000 is all I need. anyway.

I guess I cannot use Java Mail api. I have to use socket. 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/

How can I send mail from gmail using sockets in java gae? Gmail SMTPS: smtp.gmail.com port 465 and 587 are whitelisted so it is possible. Interesting but I cannot find any "hello world" example on web. I do not attach any file in the mail. Just send "hello world" from example@gmail.com (of course I have the password of the mail account) using socket.

Answer (score 0):

[ignore]

You need to use the mail service, but you can split the recipients list into several lists of up to a 100 each (in your example - 10 such lists) and send the same mail to each of the lists separately.

[/ignore]

**EDIT**

You can use Amazon Simple Email Service who has HTTP api http://aws.amazon.com/ses/

Comment: no i can't. I cannot send more than 100 mails a day. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Mail